# Where to put redirect logic in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

I created a custom module that redirects the user based on various custom rules. My problem is figuring out where to place the code. Right now, I have:

```
function mymodule_init() {
    mymodule_redirect_now();
}
```

The "mymodule_redirect_now" generally does not do anything in most cases, but sometimes it may result in "drupal_goto" being fired off. This works in practice, but causes other issues:

1. Any of the cron files automatially also fails. (i.e. cron.php)
2. Unit tests fail (as in they can't finish because this "goto" is seen as a failure)

Where would be the most correct place to put redirect logic like this, to avoid failing unit tests and failing cron jobs?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to simplify this question, by rather bringing it down to one more simple question. Basically, I want to know how to stop cron from executing the following code:

```
function mymodule_init() {
    mymodule_redirect_now();
}
```

Cron always executes anything in init, but in this case, let's imagine that the redirect has the following logic:

```
function mymodule_redirect_now()
{
    if (!$currentPathIsUS && $ipIsUS) { // lets pretend for now this always happens...
         drupal_goto("us");
    }
}
```

Basically, if the use has a US IP and the current path is not the US path, it must redirect them to the /us path.

The problem is, if I run cron from the command line, or from a browser, it hits the above code before moving on to any other function, but because of the "drupal_goto", it doesnt ever actually execute the cron code.

1. Is it bad practice to do what I am doing above? and if so, what is the better alternative?
2. How can I stop cron from executing the init code in this case?

Answer (score 4):

`hook_init()` will always run at the start of the request as you have noticed.

When you say "… redirects the user based on various custom rules." what do you mean? Is the user being redirected when submitting a form with some content? Is the user being redirected if visiting a (or a set of) specific URL's? What conditions are there? Is it the [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)?

Depending on which custom rules you mean there will be different answers. For example if the rules has something to do with nodes (loading, viewing, editing, …) you have to use `hook_node_$op()` where `$op` can be e.g.  "view", or "load", or "submit". As an example:

```
// Redirect user when submitting a node of type 'book'
function mymodule_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  if ($node->type === 'book') {
    drupal_goto("some/place/else");
  }
}
```

There are two issues at play here as I see it. One is *where in the code to place redirect logic* which in Drupal 7 (and 6) does not really have a good short answer, it all depends on the context. It could be in response to a form *loading* or a form *submitting* or a node *loading* or *viewing* or *editing* (et.c.) or a number of other conditions. These conditions necessitate that the redirect logic be on different places in your code. This is what I was concentrating on answering above.

The second issue, which upon reading your clarifications seems to be the main culprit, is of a different type. Cron and unit tests will not have all the info a regular web browser visitor have.

You will have to detect if [cron is running](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7) and not redirect when that happens. As you see on in the link above cron creates a temporary (anonymous) user and won't save any session data. This has a tendency to break many cron runs. Because [`drupal_exit()` more or less kills everything](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7).

As for unit testing `drupal_goto()`, I am less sure here, but I believe it breaks for the same reason. You could try to mock part of the function to actually not redirect.

And as a side note you may want to consider using [hook_url_inbound_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) ([more info](http://andyclabaugh.com/thoughts/url-altering-in-drupal)). It might or might not be compatible with exactly what you want to do. Look at what the Redirect module does, especially the function `redirect_can_redirect()`.

Comment: I am using init as a place from which I do checks, and based on that, redirect the user using drupal_goto. Problem is, this breaks unit testing and cron jobs too, because in some cases they are triggering the rules. So without making specific exceptions for certain paths, I would like to know, what is the general way to deal with setting up rules that redirect a user that rely on the first time they hit the server?

Comment: There is no "general way", the way is dependent upon what you are testing against, unless we are talking about the Rules module (which has its own [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/rules)). All visitors who are not logged in in Drupal are the same user (User ID 0), this means that you can not save a variable on the user object to check against, but I suspect you might solve this with `user_cookie_save($values)`. Depending on what your actual conditions are you will have to use different Drupal hooks to achieve your redirect.

Comment: Are we on a common understanding with this pseudo-code:  `if ($visitor_hits_server_first_time === true) { then_only_do_redirect_once(); }`?

Comment: Almost correct. It does the check each time. But for my question, it is almost irrelevant. I am trying to understand where to place logic that will not break unit tests if I use drupal_goto and drupal_exit. The init function is also called by cron, so having redirects in there breaks cron. So how would I deal with this case? This is more correct --> if ($user_hits_server && $user_requires_redirect_due_to_some_condition) {  redirect_user(); }

Comment: Basically, I am checking the user's IP address and I'm checking locale and a few other things and based on these custom rules I redirect the user. But I dont know where to put this custom logic that won't break unit tests or cron?

Comment: "where to place logic that will not break unit tests if I use drupal_goto and drupal_exit" is not the correct way to deal with the issue you are describing. There is no specific place to place conditional logic because it depends on its context. You must instead solve the issue by making sure to only run drupal_goto() and drupal_exit() if and only if they are supposed to run. The dummy user created when cron runs does not contain all data as a normal visitor, nor does it have a UA/lang/session. Anyway, it seems you are asking two things: 1) How to identify corn/unit test 2) How to do redirects

Comment: Ok, it is a bit clearer now what you want to do. I have tried to expand on my answer now.